# Calculate total time without overlapping time

Tags: sql, sql-server

MSSQL 2016

Currently I have the following table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4GX6.png

OwnerName = Jan is working this day from 07.00 till 15.30. This means his total working time should be 8.5 hours. However, when I SUM the total minutes I got a lot more since he has overlapping activities. How could I exclude these overlapping activities and calculate his total working time on this day: 
2017-09-12.

Now, this table contains not only data for 2017-09-12 but for every day there are activities planned. So the query should take this in account aswell. Furthermore, there are multiple owners in this table i.e. Luc. this is also somehting that the query should handle.

Can someone help me? :)

EDIT: To make things clearer. The result should be in the following format

```
|------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|      Ownername         |     Date         |  Time in hours |
|------------------------|------------------|----------------|
|          Jan           |   2017-09-12     |   8.5          | 
|          Luc           |   2017-09-12     |   8.5          |
|          John          |   2017-09-12     |   8.5          |
|          Doe           |   2017-09-11     |   7            |
|          Jan           |   2017-09-13     |   4            | 
|          Doe           |   2017-09-14     |   8.5          |
|          Tom           |   2017-09-14     |   7            |
```

My current guess is that I first have to determine which activities are overlapping. I think I have to use the BETWEEN statement to do that. Then use the CASE statement to not add this time to the total time in hours for that day.

Comment: "this is also somehting that the query should handle." - maybe so - but *in what way*? You're saying things should be handled but not making it clear what result you're looking for. Are you looking for a single total across all owners? Or are you looking for individual totals for each owner for each day? Or something else? Either of those options would be "handling" all of the data.

Comment: Please show what did you tried and where is your actual problem which stop you to proceed? For now it seems like you asking us to do your job ;)

Comment: No your requirement is not clear.your explanation is not in tandem with your input.What is total work time of Luc from your input 3 hr or 2.5 hr.Explain 1 or 2 example calculation including overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with SUM keyword. Instead try using DATEDIFF.
It will be accurate and if you have multiple records for each day use CURSOR so that you can take evry record uniqeuly.

For example use DATEDIFF in a CURSOR and THEN SUM the result of that

Comment: OP tell nothing about any specific problems

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try the following solution. It removes intervals that are contained in some other one and then it uses the `LAG` window function to access the previous row and update the intervals to have non-overlapping ones. Then we can simply perform the `SUM`.

```
WITH
     inputs ( name, date_fr, date_to ) AS (
       select 'Dan'    , cast('07-Jun-17 08:00:00' as DATETIME), cast('07-Jun-17 10:00:00' as DATETIME) union all
       select 'Dan'  , cast('07-Jun-17 11:00:00' as DATETIME), cast('07-Jun-17 12:00:00' as DATETIME) union all
       select 'Jan' , cast('08-Jun-17 08:15:00' as DATETIME), cast('08-Jun-17 15:00:00' as DATETIME) union all
       select 'Jan' , cast('08-Jun-17 08:15:00' as DATETIME), cast('08-Jun-17 10:00:00' as DATETIME) union all
       select 'Jan'    , cast('07-Jun-17 08:30:00' as DATETIME), cast('07-Jun-17 15:00:00' as DATETIME) union all
       select 'Jan'    , cast('07-Jun-17 09:00:00' as DATETIME), cast('07-Jun-17 9:30:00' as DATETIME) union all
       select 'Jan' , cast('07-Jun-17 08:00:00' as DATETIME), cast('07-Jun-17 10:00:00' as DATETIME)
     )
-- End of simulated input (for testing only, not part of the solution).
SELECT name, year(date_fr) year, month(date_fr) month, day(date_fr) day, 
       sum(cast(datediff(minute, date_fr, date_to) as decimal(10,4)))/60
FROM
    (
        SELECT t.name,
               CASE WHEN lag(date_to) over (partition by name order by date_fr) > date_fr 
                    THEN lag(date_to) over (partition by name order by date_fr) 
                    ELSE date_fr 
               END date_fr, 
               t.date_to
        FROM
        (
            SELECT name, date_fr, date_to
            FROM   inputs i1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROm inputs i2 WHERE i1.name = i2.name and i2.date_fr < i1.date_fr and i2.date_to > i1.date_to) -- this removes fully nested intervals
        ) t
    ) tt
WHERE tt.date_fr < tt.date_to
GROUP BY name, year(date_fr), month(date_fr), day(date_fr)
```